# Parametise using an IN condition in SQL in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, parameter-passing

I have just started parametising all my queries as I should have long ago!

So my aim was to create a "parametising function" which returned an ADO recordset.

I have created arrays which I send over to the function.

This is working fine except if in the SQL string i use something like

> SELECT * FROM tblChemists WHERE chemistID in (?) AND chemName LIKE "%"
>   AND chemDelFee = 5.5

In this situation it doesnt bug out but only returns the first record that I have referred to in the (?) section.
eg. when i use the paramter "30,31" it returns the data for ID = 30, but if i switch it over and ask for 31,30 then I get ID 31 data!

This obviously means something is wrong with my parameter not with my sql string (which by the way if i run it manually in MYSQL WORKBENCH it gives both records)

This is the function I use.

```
Public Function getRSTparam(strSQL As String, paramValue As Variant, paramType As Variant, paramLength As Variant, Optional skip As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim Pm As ADODB.parameter
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open ADOoCon
    Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
    With Cm
        .ActiveConnection = Cn
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText

    For i = LBound(paramValue) To UBound(paramValue)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ChemID", paramType(i), adParamInput, paramLength(i), paramValue(i))
       Next i

        Set getRSTparam = .Execute
    End With

End Function
```

and this is how I call it.

```
Private Sub btnTest2_Click()
'testparam
Dim str As String


  str = "SELECT * FROM tblChemists WHERE chemistID in (?) AND chemName LIKE ? AND chemDelFee = ?"

Dim arrValue As Variant
  Dim arrType As Variant

  arrValue = Array("31,30", "%a%", 5.5)
  arrType = Array(adVarChar, adVarChar, adDouble)
  arrLength = Array(10, 50, 5)

Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set Rs = getRSTparam(str, arrValue, arrType, arrLength)

Rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print Rs.RecordCount
  Do Until Rs.EOF

Debug.Print Rs!ChemName
    Rs.MoveNext
  Loop
End Sub
```

So now I am a bit stuck as I don't know how I can use two ID's in an IN condition.